# includepdf and tableofcontents without numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, pdfpages

I try to include an entire pdf file with pdfpages but I will not use numbering in the table of contents. Here is a MWE, which illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Test}
Only a test
\addsec{Another Test}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section,1,{Another PDF},test}]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I will not number the entry in the `toc` for the included pdf. Well, I can set the number, denoting depth of section to a higher value than `tocdepth`/`secnumdepth` (which is working, like
`\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section,`**6**`,{Another PDF},test}]{test.pdf}`
).

Is there a smarter solution available?

Comment: You could say something like `{
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section,1,{Another PDF},test}]{b.pdf}
}` but I am not sure of this would be "smarter".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know the command `addsec` provided by a KOMA class. You can use this as an option of `addtotoc`:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,addsec,1,{Another PDF},test}]{test-crop.pdf}
```